# Nodejs / Express / Postgres query blocks

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I have tried a simple query to my Postgresql database, with Express and pg, but my query blocks the server before the console.log

It starts with : node app.js

Here is extract of the code of app.js

```
var router = express.Router()
const { Client } = require('pg')

const client = new Client({
    user: 'dev', 
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'fransua',
    password: 'azerty123456789',
    port: 5432
})

client.connect()

router.get('/database', async (req, res) => {
    client.query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE first_name= $1", ['Roam']), (err,res) => {
        console.log(err ? err.stack : res.rows)
        res.render("database", {title: "Database", posts: posts})
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

Create a query statement:

```
const query = {
   // give the query a unique name
   name: 'fetch-employee',
   text: 'SELECT * FROM employees WHERE first_name= $1',
   values: ['Roam'],
  }
```

Than run the operation with a promise:

```
// promise
 client
  .query(query)
  .then(res => console.log(res.rows[0]))
  .catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo. Delete the closing parenthesis after `['Roam']` and insert one after the closing brace:

```js
client.query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE first_name= $1", ['Roam'], (err,res) => {
  console.log(err ? err.stack : res.rows)
  res.render("database", {title: "Database", posts: posts})
})
```